GNU linker uses 0x200000000 as a base address for LMA and VMA
boot.s
.code16
.text
.global start
start:
        jmp start

boot.ld
ENTRY(start)

SECTIONS
{
    . = 0x00007C00; /* Set the location counter to 0x7C00 */

    .text :
    {
        *(.text)
    }

    .data :
    {
        *(.data)
    }

    .sig 0x7DFE:
    {
        SHORT(0xaa55);
    }
}

Assembling command:
as -o boot.o .\boot.s

Linking command
ld -T boot.ld -o boot.elf .\boot.o

Here I am getting:
/usr/bin/ld: boot.elf:.text: section below image base
/usr/bin/ld: boot.elf:.sig: section below image base

I don't understand these messages..
Objdump command
objdump -h -D .\boot.elf

.\boot.elf:     file format pei-x86-64

Sections:
Idx Name          Size      VMA               LMA               File off  Algn
  0 .text         00000010  0000000200007c00  0000000200007c00  00000200  2**4
                  CONTENTS, ALLOC, LOAD, READONLY, CODE
  1 .sig          00000002  0000000200007dfe  0000000200007dfe  00000400  2**2
                  CONTENTS, READONLY

Disassembly of section .text:

0000000200007c00 <start>:
   200007c00:   eb fe                   jmp    200007c00 <start>
   200007c02:   90                      nop
   200007c03:   90                      nop
   200007c04:   90                      nop
   200007c05:   90                      nop
   200007c06:   90                      nop
   200007c07:   90                      nop
   200007c08:   90                      nop
   200007c09:   90                      nop
   200007c0a:   90                      nop
   200007c0b:   90                      nop
   200007c0c:   90                      nop
   200007c0d:   90                      nop
   200007c0e:   90                      nop
   200007c0f:   90                      nop

Disassembly of section .sig:

0000000200007dfe <.sig>:
   200007dfe:   55                      push   %rbp
   200007dff:   aa                      stos   %al,%es:(%rdi)

Creating binary file command
 objcopy -O binary .\boot.elf boot.bin

boot.bin file
EB FE 90 90 90 90 90 90 90 90 90 90 90 90 90 90

Two problems:

LMA and VMA start from 200007c00 instead of 7c00.
0x55AA is missing from the binary file. I can see that the .sig section is present with objdump. I have no idea why it is not present in the binary file.

EDIT:
Forgot to mention that I am using Cygwin64 on Windows 11.

Side note: your file is not ELF, it's PE.

Pass the --image-base=0 option to the linker. Your .sig section does not have the LOAD or ALLOC flags so objcopy does not copy it. You can set it via --set-section-flags .sig=LOAD Can't find a way to do either of these from the linker script.

Did the exact same steps I did with Cygwin on WSL and everything works correctly.

The difference really is that in WSL/WSL2 you are using Linux ELF format and in Windows you are using Windows/PE32+ format (64-bit). The Windows link process is different than that of Linux and generic ELF cross compilers. Rather than be at the mercy of the Host compiler you are better off using a x86-64 Cross Compiler.
